# Date conversion in MM/DD/YY h:mm:ss a format in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to get this date 09/03/18 6:30:00 PM using 4-SEP-2018 but I am getting 12/364/17 6:30:00 PM, Here is what I have tried.

```
public class StockBuySell 

{      

    static String  DATE_FORMAT_UI = "DD-MMM-YYYY";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY h:mm:ss a");
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_UI);

        String inputText = "4-SEP-2018";
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
        String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(outputText);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you supposed to get the time from the date? Or is it just the current time? Actually how can you possibly get `09/03/18 6:30:00 PM` from `4-SEP-2018`? Different date and a random time?

Comment: Watch your case... day in month is dd (not DD) and year is yy  not YY

Comment: @achAmháin I feel like OP tries to use the date for timezone correction (09/03/18 6:30 PM  + 5.5h = 09/04/18)

Comment: @Codeer perhaps...however, if that's the case, the question is poorly phrased.

Comment: @achAmháin I am giving time zone as GMT

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Learn about `LocalDate.parse` with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.  Search Stack Overflow for many existing Questions and Answers. Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `D` stands for *Day in **year***. You will need to replace `DD` with `dd` (day in month).

`Y` stands for *Week year*, not year.

In short, this: `"DD-MMM-YYYY"` needs to be this: `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`.

Comment: thanks it got solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String  DATE_FORMAT_UI = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss a");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_UI);

String inputText = "4-SEP-2018";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(outputText);
```

You are going to have time zone issues as you're forcing the GMT... the date you're rendering will be in the local time zone so it may change the date.